# Android: Виджет из ListView на Android ниже 14 api lvl

Tags: android, java

Как можно сделать виджет на Android ниже 4.0 версии состоящий из ListView? Подскажите в какую сторону смотреть.

Comment: я был бы очень осторожным с такими вещами, как скролл в виджетах. ИМХО на рабочем столе (ланчере) не должно быть элементов, перехватывающих свайп. Даже вертикальный.

Comment: @metalurgus, но ведь g-mail-овский виджет же скролится вертикально. На мой взгяд вполне допустимая практика.